# Looking for a VNC (and or Remote Desktop) Profile Manager/Launcher

Tags: windows-7, ssh, remote-desktop, vnc

I connect to many different computers via VNC and RDP.  I'm looking for a windows client that can preferably do the following, though I'd accept software options that only meet some of the points:

- Save profiles (hostname, username, password, settings, etc.)
- Connect to VNC Servers
- Connect to RDP Servers
- Connect to SSH Servers (or ssh tunneling)
- Scan network for devices not in saved profiles
- Free (as in beer)

Tools that do similar things, but not on windows:

- ARD on OSX
- iSSH on iPad
- Desktop Connect on iPad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found and like http://www.mremoteng.org/ mRemoteNG.

Answer (score 1):

mRemote is great in most respects.
[available here](http://www.mremote.org/wiki/Downloads.ashx)